# Json Parsing and inserting to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, mandrill

I am using the the Mandrill to post any inbound emails. Here is what is posted by Mandrill when i receive a new email -> http://help.mandrill.com/entries/22092308-What-is-the-format-of-inbound-email-webhooks-

Also here is what i get in the $_REQUEST (sorry that its not formatted well):
`[{\"event\":\"inbound\",\"ts\":1361798154,\"msg\":{\"raw_msg\":\"Received: from nm11-vm1.bullet.mail.sg3.yahoo.com (nm11-vm1.bullet.mail.sg3.yahoo.com [106.10.148.240])\\n\\tby ip-10-138-250-144 (Postfix) with ESMTPS id 663A4136204D\\n\\tfor <>; Mon, 25 Feb 2013 13:15:54 +0000 (UTC)\\nReceived: from [106.10.166.112] by nm11.bullet.mail.sg3.yahoo.com with NNFMP; 25 Feb 2013 13:15:53 -0000\\nReceived: from [106.10.151.171] by tm1.bullet.mail.sg3.yahoo.com with NNFMP; 25 Feb 2013 13:15:53 -0000\\nReceived: from [127.0.0.1] by omp1011.mail.sg3.yahoo.com with NNFMP; 25 Feb 2013 13:15:53 -0000\\nX-Yahoo-Newman-Property: ymail-3\\nX-Yahoo-Newman-Id: 250040.22861.bm@omp1011.mail.sg3.yahoo.com\\nReceived: (qmail 28099 invoked by uid 60001); 25 Feb 2013 13:15:53 -0000\\nDKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed\\/relaxed; d=yahoo.co.in; s=s1024; t=1361798153; bh=BDFj0kYtFyAwYeMROJlckEQlebiL67q4OCeBIQv8Ptg=; h=X-YMail-OSG:Received:X-Rocket-MIMEInfo:X-Mailer:Message-ID:Date:From:Reply-To:Subject:To:MIME-Version:Content-Type; b=JTaQH8PfSRIt\\/tYN16h6m1TeqlfEilid7FHTCoLdgYKL1CKf1s92DXm0vNKycLvTK7vmGr61e8SOxv2yGghCgOFHEumbLrF0kz+dhDeXBzyqrMPLcXT0w4uiUTJv+YtlsXYELvzN2ULhVwE1BXst2ok\\/Fj5AxpmRSJ8\\/0lxxUrY=\\nDomainKey-Signature:a=rsa-sha1; q=dns; c=nofws;\\n  s=s1024; d=yahoo.co.in;\\n  h=X-YMail-OSG:Received:X-Rocket-MIMEInfo:X-Mailer:Message-ID:Date:From:Reply-To:Subject:To:MIME-Version:Content-Type;\\n  b=fEBcmdXcrijuQ\\/LkRh3mlZVEdQ7E\\/DzZ2rRlMZEUbr2Z6sv0SbmADNiea4a4WZImIJTyeXdgeOTrV1peLkegTUzf5UxBQW18NE0Sjlay54kAhADfgt6N+HUoiSH+Psj4gTSbOYv\\/Ij1x2CmR645JShaz2x1TfNYgvYRb05VZWv8=;\\nX-YMail-OSG: buuv6IIVM1kj3NrZiivkBVYfFcT.P8xs1KJk1zKUlFASQ5M\\n 0rxt7ojMEC0KSn8S8s4GSaBBW.f4Pd8x9V4dCr8BPKXvnvcZQhqM2Wu10meZ\\n jC.N8I7D3XXxzRI15ez1zICJg2fZkng2x5FQqUhElC.y03G6cSZJIFPSBitM\\n 0R6RnJA0zhWnWQv7UAD.KdKiKgnEPSA9lZpRqcTGHh8uNYuu6bWiKv9wXnGG\\n rzKei4dmAv5lrEhD9iXVSQCQw_2S9RzQd08B3vBg0keF3vBMBnmCCdyqdxRK\\n 4IQbYZZGBXTt3AQz.rdVxjTicu2rTvkGLkOb9JN0qA3NURs2BJYvd0TMNGQn\\n 9xWGKTIQmJ.pla6Tw8_vQUCkJuRCl7tlKavXX6U_ocY34VjDTthwKHf.pCYo\\n 8mwtfsLpHC9ZklRu4vSIM6kGZLjQoux4mz0qJduVBaYYoRboY_kH622MyI.m\\n sBA--\\nReceived: from [182.68.19.112] by web192402.mail.sg3.yahoo.com via HTTP; Mon, 25 Feb 2013 21:15:52 SGT\\nX-Rocket-MIMEInfo: 001.001,U2F5cyBXaG8BMAEBAQE-\\nX-Mailer: YahooMailWebService\\/0.8.134.513\\nMessage-ID: <1361798152.24847.YahooMailNeo@web192402.mail.sg3.yahoo.com>\\nDate: Mon, 25 Feb 2013 21:15:52 +0800 (SGT)\\nFrom: Lucky Soni <lp.soni@yahoo.co.in>\\nReply-To: Lucky Soni <lp.soni@yahoo.co.in>\\nSubject: Hello World\\nTo: \\\"\\\" <>\\nMIME-Version: 1.0\\nContent-Type: multipart\\/alternative; boundary=\\\"1577518589-1280633723-1361798152=:24847\\\"\\n\\n--1577518589-1280633723-1361798152=:24847\\nContent-Type: text\\/plain; charset=utf-8\\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\\n\\nSays Who\\n--1577518589-1280633723-1361798152=:24847\\nContent-Type: text\\/html; charset=utf-8\\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\\n\\n<html><body><div style=3D\\\"color:#000; background-color:#fff; font-family:ve=\\nrdana, helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12pt\\\"><div>Says Who<\\/div><\\/div><\\/bod=\\ny><\\/html>\\n--1577518589-1280633723-1361798152=:24847--\",\"headers\":{\"Received\":[\"from nm11-vm1.bullet.mail.sg3.yahoo.com (nm11-vm1.bullet.mail.sg3.yahoo.com [106.10.148.240]) by ip-10-138-250-144 (Postfix) with ESMTPS id 663A4136204D for <>; Mon, 25 Feb 2013 13:15:54 +0000 (UTC)\",\"from [106.10.166.112] by nm11.bullet.mail.sg3.yahoo.com with NNFMP; 25 Feb 2013 13:15:53 -0000\",\"from [106.10.151.171] by tm1.bullet.mail.sg3.yahoo.com with NNFMP; 25 Feb 2013 13:15:53 -0000\",\"from [127.0.0.1] by omp1011.mail.sg3.yahoo.com with NNFMP; 25 Feb 2013 13:15:53 -0000\",\"(qmail 28099 invoked by uid 60001); 25 Feb 2013 13:15:53 -0000\",\"from [182.68.19.112] by web192402.mail.sg3.yahoo.com via HTTP; Mon, 25 Feb 2013 21:15:52 SGT\"],\"X-Yahoo-Newman-Property\":\"ymail-3\",\"X-Yahoo-Newman-Id\":\"250040.22861.bm@omp1011.mail.sg3.yahoo.com\",\"Dkim-Signature\":\"v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed\\/relaxed; d=yahoo.co.in; s=s1024; t=1361798153; bh=BDFj0kYtFyAwYeMROJlckEQlebiL67q4OCeBIQv8Ptg=; h=X-YMail-OSG:Received:X-Rocket-MIMEInfo:X-Mailer:Message-ID:Date:From:Reply-To:Subject:To:MIME-Version:Content-Type; b=JTaQH8PfSRIt\\/tYN16h6m1TeqlfEilid7FHTCoLdgYKL1CKf1s92DXm0vNKycLvTK7vmGr61e8SOxv2yGghCgOFHEumbLrF0kz+dhDeXBzyqrMPLcXT0w4uiUTJv+YtlsXYELvzN2ULhVwE1BXst2ok\\/Fj5AxpmRSJ8\\/0lxxUrY=\",\"Domainkey-Signature\":\"a=rsa-sha1; q=dns; c=nofws; s=s1024; d=yahoo.co.in; h=X-YMail-OSG:Received:X-Rocket-MIMEInfo:X-Mailer:Message-ID:Date:From:Reply-To:Subject:To:MIME-Version:Content-Type; b=fEBcmdXcrijuQ\\/LkRh3mlZVEdQ7E\\/DzZ2rRlMZEUbr2Z6sv0SbmADNiea4a4WZImIJTyeXdgeOTrV1peLkegTUzf5UxBQW18NE0Sjlay54kAhADfgt6N+HUoiSH+Psj4gTSbOYv\\/Ij1x2CmR645JShaz2x1TfNYgvYRb05VZWv8=;\",\"X-Ymail-Osg\":\"buuv6IIVM1kj3NrZiivkBVYfFcT.P8xs1KJk1zKUlFASQ5M 0rxt7ojMEC0KSn8S8s4GSaBBW.f4Pd8x9V4dCr8BPKXvnvcZQhqM2Wu10meZ jC.N8I7D3XXxzRI15ez1zICJg2fZkng2x5FQqUhElC.y03G6cSZJIFPSBitM 0R6RnJA0zhWnWQv7UAD.KdKiKgnEPSA9lZpRqcTGHh8uNYuu6bWiKv9wXnGG rzKei4dmAv5lrEhD9iXVSQCQw_2S9RzQd08B3vBg0keF3vBMBnmCCdyqdxRK 4IQbYZZGBXTt3AQz.rdVxjTicu2rTvkGLkOb9JN0qA3NURs2BJYvd0TMNGQn 9xWGKTIQmJ.pla6Tw8_vQUCkJuRCl7tlKavXX6U_ocY34VjDTthwKHf.pCYo 8mwtfsLpHC9ZklRu4vSIM6kGZLjQoux4mz0qJduVBaYYoRboY_kH622MyI.m sBA--\",\"X-Rocket-Mimeinfo\":\"001.001,U2F5cyBXaG8BMAEBAQE-\",\"X-Mailer\":\"YahooMailWebService\\/0.8.134.513\",\"Message-Id\":\"<1361798152.24847.YahooMailNeo@web192402.mail.sg3.yahoo.com>\",\"Date\":\"Mon, 25 Feb 2013 21:15:52 +0800 (SGT)\",\"From\":\"Lucky Soni <lp.soni@yahoo.co.in>\",\"Reply-To\":\"Lucky Soni <lp.soni@yahoo.co.in>\",\"Subject\":\"Hello World\",\"To\":\"\\\"\\\" <>\",\"Mime-Version\":\"1.0\",\"Content-Type\":\"multipart\\/alternative; boundary=\\\"1577518589-1280633723-1361798152=:24847\\\"\"},\"text\":\"Says Who\\n\",\"html\":\"<html><body><div style=\\\"color:#000; background-color:#fff; font-family:verdana, helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12pt\\\"><div>Says Who<\\/div><\\/div><\\/body><\\/html>\\n\",\"from_email\":\"lp.soni@yahoo.co.in\",\"from_name\":\"Lucky Soni\",\"to\":[[\"\",\"\"]],\"subject\":\"Hello World\",\"email\":\"\",\"tags\":[],\"sender\":null}}]`

I need to get the "text" (please use "ctrl/command + F" to find the word "text" :)
and then insert into mySQl. Please help.
Thanks

Note: I have already tried json_deocde but it does not work gor me.

Comment: How to Google: `<programming language> <encode type> <action>` => `php json decode` ( https://www.google.com/?q=php+json+decode )

Comment: already tried json_deocde but it didnt work for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you try to decode your json with json_deocde ?
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: probably won't work directly. that json looks like it's been mangled with magic quotes.

Comment: I just try. It work for me with json_decode. No problem with magic quotes

Comment: Yes i tried it but it gives an empty result... also used the stripslashes() but didnt work for me

Comment: Strange.
I just try this, and i've got an array

Comment: worked for me too now.. strange i tried it like 20 times.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I ended up pulling the raw HTTP POST and using urldecode() first than running json_decode.